# C++ Multibyte/wide character conversions (cuchar) not working in MS VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, std

I've recently started using Microsoft Visual Studio Code on my Windows PC and integrated the terminal with it to run/debug C/C++ programs (reference: [How to Write And Run C and C++ Code in Visual Studio Code](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-and-run-c-cpp-code-on-visual-studio-code)).

However, while executing certain programs, I'm getting compilation error messages such as below:

> 'mbrtoc16' has not been declared in '::'
> 'c16rtomb' has not been declared in '::'
> 'mbrtoc32' has not been declared in '::'
> 'c32rtomb' has not been declared in '::'

May I get help on fixing these, please? I get the errors while debugging/running the below C++ program in VS Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);
vector<string> split(const string &);

vector<int> freqQuery(vector<vector<int>> queries) {
    int index=0, choice, value, flag;
    vector<int> result;
    unordered_map<int,int> contents;
    unordered_map<int,int> :: iterator content_itr;
    vector<vector<int>> :: iterator query_itr = queries.begin();
    while(query_itr < queries.end()){
        choice = query_itr[0][0];
        value = query_itr[0][1];
        flag = -1;
        if(choice == 1){
            content_itr = contents.find(value);
            if(content_itr == contents.end())
                contents.insert(make_pair(value, 1));                
            else
                content_itr->second += 1;                
        }   
        else if(choice == 2) {
            content_itr = contents.find(value);
            if(content_itr != contents.end())
                content_itr->second -= 1;
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            for(content_itr = contents.begin(); content_itr != contents.end(); content_itr++)
                if(content_itr->second == value){
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            if(flag == 1)
                result.push_back(1);
            else
                result.push_back(0);
        }
        query_itr++;
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    string q_temp;
    getline(cin, q_temp);

    int q = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(q_temp)));

    vector<vector<int>> queries(q);

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        queries[i].resize(2);

        string queries_row_temp_temp;
        getline(cin, queries_row_temp_temp);

        vector<string> queries_row_temp = split(rtrim(queries_row_temp_temp));

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            int queries_row_item = stoi(queries_row_temp[j]);

            queries[i][j] = queries_row_item;
        }
    }

    vector<int> ans = freqQuery(queries);

    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
        fout << ans[i];

        if (i != ans.size() - 1) {
            fout << "\n";
        }
    }

    fout << "\n";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

string ltrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        s.begin(),
        find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace)))
    );

    return s;
}

string rtrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))).base(),
        s.end()
    );

    return s;
}

vector<string> split(const string &str) {
    vector<string> tokens;

    string::size_type start = 0;
    string::size_type end = 0;

    while ((end = str.find(" ", start)) != string::npos) {
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));

        start = end + 1;
    }

    tokens.push_back(str.substr(start));

    return tokens;
}
```

One way I could figure out to suppress those errors is by commenting out the the line `#include <cuchar>` in the header file named `stdc++.h`. However, I believe this is just a workaround that might impact something else possibly, and not an absolute solution.

Comment: Make sure you are compiling for C++11 or later. Also, see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/) Use `#include <cuchar>` directly in your own code (also, given the code shown, you will also need `<string>`,  `<vector>`, `<unordered_map>`, `<fstream>`, and `<algorithm>`, too).